# Plot two series on same graph that begin on different dates

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I've got two series that I want to plot on the same graph. Unfortunately the series do not begin on the same date.

```
> head(spend_df)
        date   spend
1 2012-05-24 1754.73
2 2012-05-25 3270.75
3 2012-05-26 3168.60
4 2012-05-27 3963.20
5 2012-05-28 3123.68

> head(subs_df)
        date     subs
1 2013-11-08 820.8462
2 2013-11-09 801.5087
3 2013-11-10 820.0475
4 2013-11-11 842.5435
5 2013-11-12 848.4188
```

Is there a way to plot these two series so that the observations match up with the appropriate dates?

The code below currently generates:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMpjx.png

[image: plot]

And here is the code I'm using:

```
spend_df <- read.table('C:\\Users\\...spend.csv',header=TRUE,sep=',')
subs_df <- read.table('C:\\Users\\...subs.csv', header=TRUE,sep=',')
colnames(spend_df) <- c("date", "spend") 
colnames(subs_df) <- c("date", "subs")

interval <- 60
with(spend_df, plot(spend, xlab="", ylab="", type='l', axes=FALSE))

axis(2)     
axis(1, labels = FALSE, at=seq(1,nrow(spend_df),interval))

boolean_interval <- c(TRUE,c(rep(FALSE,interval-1)))
ticks <- spend_df$date[boolean_interval]
text(seq(1, length(spend_df$date), interval), par("usr")[3] + 1, srt = 45, adj = 1,     labels = ticks, xpd = TRUE)
box()

par(new=T)
plot(subs_df$subs, axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", type='l')
```

Comment: Can you do a `dput()` of each of your `head()`'s and are you limited to base graphics or is a solution in `ggplot2` acceptable?

Comment: Use `range()` to get the min and max dates, then set `plot(.., xlim = date.range)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution using the ggplot2 package ( keep in mind that the solution is basically a one-liner. Most of the code is necessary to reconstruct the missing data frames ):

```
df <- data.frame(seq(c(ISOdate(2013,3,20)), by = "day", length.out = 10),sample.int(20,10,replace=TRUE))
names(df) <- c("date","value")
df$desc <- rep("spend",10)
df1 <- data.frame(seq(c(ISOdate(2013,3,25)), by = "day", length.out = 10),sample.int(20,10,replace=TRUE))
names(df1) <- c("date","value")
df1$desc <- rep("subs",10)
```

Bind the 2 data frames by row and plot

```
require(ggplot2)
dfcombi <- rbind(df,df1)
ggplot(dfcombi,aes(date,value,colour=desc)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! works great! I guess its about time I use ggplot2 and now just the basic stuff that comes with R

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the two together and then use lattice. I can't test my code because I don't have your data, but

```
library(lattice)
colnames(spend_df) <- c("date", "val")
spend_df$set <- "spend" 
colnames(subs_df) <- c("date", "val")
subs_df$set <- "subs"

df <- rbind(spend_df, subs_df)

xyplot(val ~ date, data=df, groups=set, auto.key=TRUE)
```